# C#: Block ads in GeckoFX based browser?

Tags: c#, browser, gecko, geckofx, adblock

I'm wondering if it is possible to block ads on my GeckoFX (https://bitbucket.org/geckofx) based browser?

Answer (score -1):

You may use something like

```cs
GeckoPreferences.[Default]("extensions.blocklist.enabled") = True
```

in order to perform the block.

Comment: GeckoPreferences.[Default]("extensions.blocklist.enabled") = False